# Google map issue even all setting is correct according to google doc

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I have implemented google map according to [google map api documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start).

**Activity code is here**

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap map;
    double latitude,longitude;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map_layout);
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("lat"));
        longitude =Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("lng"));
             SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }
}
```

**xml layout**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    </uses-feature>
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"></uses-feature>
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" >
    </uses-feature>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <permission
        android:name="pws.nactus.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="pws.nactus.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="pws.nactus.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK">

    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="pws.nactus.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- permission for Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <!-- Camera features - recommended -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />


    <!-- Permission to vibrate - recommended, allows vibration feedback on scan -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaS*****************uPTJkdnEn7dvdM" />

        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <activity
            android:name=".GoogleMapActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           />

                </application>
</manifest>
```

**We have also added sha-1 for google map key**

[image]

**Result Screen (Map)**

[image]

**Console logs**

```
07-20 14:52:29.315 8434-12620/pws.nactus V/FA: Activity paused, time: 786941945
07-20 14:52:29.318 8434-12620/pws.nactus D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=2996, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=TutorProfileActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4288618532452179711}]
07-20 14:52:29.371 8434-8434/pws.nactus V/FA: onActivityCreated
07-20 14:52:29.429 8434-8434/pws.nactus I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11055436
07-20 14:52:29.480 8434-12730/pws.nactus E/Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
07-20 14:52:29.522 8434-12620/pws.nactus V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 786942133
07-20 14:52:29.524 8434-12620/pws.nactus D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=TutorProfileActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4288618532452179711, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=GooleMapActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4288618532452179713}]
```

**Google play service version is 11.0.2 in build.gradle file**

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2"

It seems code, developer console settings and manifest settings are perfect. but we can't understand where is conflict coming from.
If any one also get this type of issue please help us to revolve it.
it will be really appreciated with lot of +1.

**This code is working in separate project to display map with same developer Console settings.**

Comment: Have you added seperate API key files for debug and release?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but for `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` you have your actual key instead of the placeholder string "key", right?

Comment: @ Iulian Popescu  we are using same api key for both.

Comment: @ Iulian Popescu we are using actual key in place of "key".

Comment: Did you enable google maps v2 API in the developer console?

Comment: Is your key restricted? i.e can only certain IP adresses authorised in dev console use it? remove all restrictions from the key and try that

Comment: @AkhileshPatil yes, we have.

Comment: @MichaelStoddart we checked it in both way by restriction and by removing restriction.

Comment: try to recheck the package name

Comment: @AkhileshPatil package name is also correct.

Comment: what about  SHA?

Comment: @AkhileshPatil dear, all things are set, why are you asking these silly questions ? I already mentioned this in question, please read question first then answer.

Comment: my mistake I skip that above section, that's why I asked you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

Above Error log shows that this is an authentication issue.

If you have implemented SSL certificate then it may having problem with host name verification that restricting your google map api when hitting on map activity startup.

You need to allow google map api when verifying host name. For more information read documentation below.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs

Comment: then verify google.com to HostnameVerifier and check again

Answer (score 0):

Here in Below tagged in your manifiest file

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR GOOGLE KEY" />
```

Put your google map key instead of 'Key' in your manifiest and **Make sure you must need to enable api from Google developer console.**

Comment: Dear @Chirag SolankI, we are using actual key instead of "key" please ignore this. I'm putting actual key there.

Comment: Check edit and Make sure you must required to used latest version of play service in your device and also in gradle.

Comment: Google play service version is 11.0.2 in build.gradle file
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2"

Comment: If everything is fine than it's might be something missing in Google developer console and I also having one suggestion.you are using so many redundant permission try to remove unused permission.
I am too much exicted for your solution.If you find solution than please share It's might be helpfull to someone.

Best of Luck

Comment: sure, we love to share solution if found, as we mentioned in question that everything is set to developer console and permissions that talking about we needed all in project, we also have other module besides map module in it.